# Не последовательно выполняется программа. Почему?

Tags: java

Я собрал простую функцию, которая получает массив с числами и дублирует каждую ячейку, но случайно наткнулся, что при выполнении вот кода:

```
public static ArrayList<String> doubleValues(ArrayList<String> list)
{
    //напишите тут ваш код

    System.out.println("open");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); )
    {
        list.add(i, list.get(i));
        i = i + 2;
    }
    System.out.println("close");

    return list;
}
```

в логе показывает вот такое выполнение :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
open
close
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
10
10
```

Исходя из вывода видно, что я передаю массив чисел от 1 до 10. Функция `doubleValues()` принимает массив и сразу же выполняет `System.out.println("open")` и `System.out.println("close")`, а потом цикл... Насколько я понимаю, должен сначала выполниться вывод `System.out.println("open")`, потом цикл и потом `System.out.println("close")`. Почему программа работает иначе?

Comment: Этого вопроса можно было бы избежать, если бы вы потрудились создать  [краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),

Comment: это даже не массив с числами, это лист стрингов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не выводите на экран полученные данные непосредственно в методе, а только заполняете их, передавая результат в другое место для вывода на экран. Надписи же *open* и *close* выводит сам метод - первую перед заполнением массива данными, вторую - после заполнения, никакого вывода на экран полученного массива в данном цикле нет.

Соответственно, программа работает не "иначе", а абсолютно правильно: вывод на экран текущего массива в другом методе, преобразование методом `doubleValues()`, который выводит *open* перед началом преобразования и *close* в конце преобразования. Затем выводите на экран полученный результат в другом методе.

PS: кстати, использовать лист из `String` для хранения `int` негуманно.